# ¿Cómo obtener los parametros de la url de una petición de http.server(SIMPLEHTTPSERVER)?

Tags: python, http

He estado haciendo muchas cosas y nada funciona.
Tengo un servidor http (`http.simple` alias para `SimpleHTTPServer`) y quiero que cuando el usuario mande parámetros con get, se guarden en una variable.

Ayúda, por favor.

edit:

mi codigo:

```
import os
import socket

ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
fip = ip+":80"

print("server:"+fip)

#guarda la ip
f = open("ip.txt", "w")
f.write(fip)
f.close()

os.system("ota.bat") #inicializa ngrok

os.system("python -m http.server 80 > nul")

#borrar el archivo con la ip
f = open("ip.txt", "w")
f.write("")
f.close()
```

version de python:3.8.5

Comment: Publica lo que has hecho (configuración, código, resultados).

Comment: Por favor, lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. En qué versión de python lo estás haciendo? Qué es http.simple? python3 ya no tiene SimpleHTTPServer, ahora está el módulo [http.server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html). Para inspeccionar y responder las peticiones get, se suele heredar de [http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html#http.server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler) e implementar do_GET.

Comment: ok ya voy a añadir los detalles

Answer (score 0):

Se puede acceder a los parámetros de la petición GET de la siguiente forma:

```
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler
from socketserver import TCPServer
from urllib.parse import parse_qsl

PUERTO = 80

class Handler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.end_headers()

        if "?" in self.path:
            _, squery = self.path.split("?", maxsplit=1)

            query = dict(parse_qsl(squery))

            self.wfile.write(str(query).encode("utf-8"))
        else:
            self.wfile.write(b"No hay parametros")

with TCPServer(("localhost", PUERTO), Handler) as httpd:
    print(f"Escuchando en el puerto {PUERTO}")
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Lo más importante pasa dentro de do_GET, que es el método llamado al recibir una
petición GET. Primero se usa send_response para enviar el código de estado (200 es OK)
y end_headers para indicar que no se envian más encabezados HTTP.

Luego, si esta el separador de los parametros y la ruta ("?"), se separa los
parámetros de la ruta y se los procesa con parse_qsl. Como parse_qsl devuelve
una lista con cada parametro como tupla `(llave, valor)`, se crea un
diccionario con esa lista.

Por ultimo se la envia al navegador con self.wfile, que es un objeto con la
"interfaz" de un archivo de salida.

Si se accede con "http://localhost:80/?param1=valor1&param2=valor2" se obtiene
en `query`:

```
{'param1': 'valor1', 'param2': 'valor2'}
```